# Изменение .bin в с++

Tags: c++, файлы, visual-c++, файловая-система

Имеется бинарный файл, логически разделенный на несколько частей. Проблема в том, что я не хочу загружать всю информацию в оперативную память, а функция `fopen()` позволяет только дописывать данные к файлу. Мои же запросы могут быть, например, такими: записать следующие данные в файл с 512-го байта по 1024-ый...

Как мне изменить данные в файле? Как можно перемещаться пой файлу, если я знаю необходимую мне позицию в нем?

P.S. Проект реализуется в VC++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы работаете через `FILE`, то вам помогут функции `ftell` (возвращает текущую позицию в файле) и `fseek` (устанавливает текущую позицию). Становитесь на 512-й байт и пишете то, что вам нужно.

P.S. Стандартные функции, не только для VC++.

Comment: А разве я смогу редактировать уже существующий файл?

Comment: Вы можете перезаписывать части файла. Открывайте его как `"r+b"`.

Comment: Т е просто установив указатель на нужную мне позицию, и просто используя fwrite с ключом r+b, я буду заменять биты, на те, которые мне нужны?

Comment: Слушайте, ну ведь просто спросив у Гугла "стать на нужную позицию в файле C++" вы вторым пунктом получаете [Лекции по C/C++: работа с файлами (stdio.h)](http://blog.kislenko.net/show.php?id=1401&s=0) - ну хоть немного поработайте самостоятельно! Если все разжевать и в рот положить - это уже будет не ваша программа...